# Returning a record at the before load stage using nlapiLoadRecord in a User Event

Tags: netsuite

I want to display a button on a Sales order only if a custom field on the Sales Order is populated.  I have a User Event script (shown below) which runs "before load" to add the button.  That part works but I want nlapiLoadRecord to return a record at the "before load" stage so I can check to see if the field is populated or not.  I have not been successful in returning a record and I don't know if this is actually possible [?]  Can someone help me out?

```
function BeforeLoad(type, form) {

  if (type=='view') {
    form.setScript('customscript_instruction_script');
    form.addButton("custpage_mybutton", "Instructions", "instruction_click();");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get the value of a field from the actual record that is being loaded, there is no need to call `nlapiLoadRecord()`. You can simply retrieve the value using `nlapiGetFieldValue()`:

```
if (type=='view') {
  var customFieldValue = nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_mycustomfield');
  if(customFieldValue === "123") {
    form.setScript('customscript_instruction_script');
    form.addButton("custpage_mybutton", "Instructions", "instruction_click();");
  }
}
```

However if the custom field is from a different record, you will need to retrieve it either by loading that record or running a search. In general `nlapiLookupField()` would be the most lightweight option.